# Boolean Comparison in df

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am  trying to write to a dataframe for values in a column which lie between a certain hex values range. How do I implement the comparison for boolean dtype.

```
if(r_adr.between(int('40000000',base=16),int('5FFFFFFF',base=16)))== True:
        data['Read_Block']='ExtMem_2'
```

The length of `r_adr` and `data` are different.

Comment: what is `r_adr` ? Can you add some data sample?

Comment: `r_adr` is a single column df with hex values converted into int. I want to write to the main df after comparison

Answer (score 0):

`(r_adr.between(int('40000000',base=16),int('5FFFFFFF',base=16)))` is a `Tuple`, so it will never be `True` (`Boolean` type). Also, I think it's `== True` not `is True`